# what might be the query to fetch all the records seperated by comma in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In SQL, suppose i have a table employee and have a column as Name containing all the names in the format FirstName,LastName. Ex:Nayeem,Khan . I want to fetch all the last names only ie Khan.

Comment: how can i accept until i get what i want

Comment: If you haven't got what you want, then identify what you actually need and why the suggestions you've been offered don't satisfy your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORACLE or MySQL solution

```
select DISTINCT SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,',')+1)
  from employee
```

**EDIT**

For SQL Server, try

```
select SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(',',name)+1,999) 
  from employee
```

assumes that name will always contain a ,

Comment: Its giving output as it is. as per my example o/p is still Nayeem,Khan.

Comment: Try reversing the ',' and name arguments in the CHARINDEX function, as I've done in my example

Answer (score 1):

In oracle, that would be

```
select substr(name, 1, instr(name. ',') - 1) as first_name,
       substr(name, instr(name. ',') + 1) as last_name
from TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: I would also suggest trimming each substr result in case there are spaces before/after the comma

Comment: kindly give solution for SQL server 2005 DB

Comment: If you'd wanted SQL server 2005 DB, it would have been better if you'd let us know that right from the start

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned the DB. You can try something like in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(",",name)+1)
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Like that but the 'WHERE' lost an E in translation and became WHRE

Comment: I think he also wants to extract the last name only but the function to use depends on his DBMS

Comment: Khan is just an example.this will give all the names ending with ,khan. I want only lastname from the column name

Answer (score 0):

Here a postgreSQL solution :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name from ',(.+)$') FROM table;


SELECT SUBSTRING('foo,bar' from ',(.+)$') ;
 substring
-----------
 bar
(1 row)
```

Comment: its saying- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'. i am using sql server 2005

Comment: It's for postgreSQL, i don't know SQL Server. But may be there is some similar function.